# Autocompletebox toolkit check mouse down

Tags: wpf, xaml, autocompletebox

I have an `AutocompleteBox` for WPF that looks like this:

```
 <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox 
     Name="AutoCompleteBox"
     DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=Users}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
     ValueMemberPath="Username"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate}" 
     PreviewMouseDown="AutoCompleteBox_OnPreviewMouseDown"/>
```

It works perfectly while navigating with arrow down/up. But I would like it to **select an item on mouse click**.

I've tried to attach the `PreviewMouseDown` as seen, but when I try to recover information, I'm failing:

```
private void AutoCompleteBox_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.ListBox listBox = AutoCompleteBox.Template.FindName("Selector", AutoCompleteBox) as System.Windows.Controls.ListBox;
    if (listBox == null) return;

    MessageBox.Show("Mouse click!");
}
```

Where `Selector` is the inner identifier for the `AutocompleteBox` listbox. But it says it doesn't have any items...

How can I simulate a mouse down on an Autocompletebox? Or how can I retreive this inner `ListBox`so I can get the selected information?